# Como criar ForeignKey sem dados com laravel

Tags: laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.5

Estou criando um sistema e tenho duas colunas: `empresas` e `usuarios`. O `usuarios.id_empresa` faz é a foreign key de `empresas.id_empresa`, contudo, alguns dados das duas tabelas são preenchidos simultaneamente  e depois do registro feito é que as demais informações poderão ser inseridas. Porém, se eu rodar `php artisan migrate` sem ter dados na tabela `empresas` aparece o erro que não pode faz essa ligação entre as tabelas justamente por `empresas` ainda não ter dados. Como resolver isso?

O furmulário de registro vai tem os inputs (entre parentes em qual tabela pertence)

Nome (usuarios)
Empresa (empresas)
Telefone (empresas)
E-mail (empresas)
senha (usuarios)

Vejam que este formulário vai popular duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo, então, preciso fazer referência de `usuarios.id_empresas` em `empresas.id_empresa`.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->integer('user_empresa')->unsigned();
        $table->string('user_nome');
        $table->string('user_email')->unique();
        $table->string('user_cpf')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('user_rg')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('user_telefone')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_senha');
        $table->boolean('user_ativo');
        $table->string('user_permissions');
        $table->integer('user_profile')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
        /* $table->foreign('user_empresa')
                 ->references('empresa_id')
                 ->on('empresas')->onDelete('cascade');*/
    });
}
```

---

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('empresas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('empresa_id');
        $table->string('empresa_nome');
        $table->string('empresa_email')->unique();
        $table->string('empresa_cnpj_cpf')->nullable();
        $table->string('empresa_telefone');
        $table->boolean('empresa_trial')->default(1);
        $table->boolean('empresa_ativo')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('empresa_cad_completo')->default(0);
        $table->string('empresa_plano')->default(0);
        $table->date('empresa_expira');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: a  
  lter table `users` add constraint `users_user_empresa_foreign` foreign key (`u  
  ser_empresa`) references `empresas` (`empresa_id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: Eu sei que esse erro dá por causa que a tabela empresas não possui dados ainda mas como resolver isso se preciso fazer a relação das tabelas mesmo sem ainda ter dados?

Comment: Coloque a migration